# How Can I count the clicking URL by User?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {

      $title=$rows['title'];
      $desc=$rows['description'];
      $url=$rows['url'];
      //include 'index.php';
      echo "<a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br><a href='$url'>$url"</a><p>";
      }
```

In this part different `$url` will be shown in the screen to the user and user can click any url to show the data.I want to count which url clicked how many times to give the page ranking??

Comment: please do ajax call onclick event on <a> tag

Answer (score 1):

Use a mediator file instead of directly linking to the url

The mediator PHP file will count how many times it has been called (use a counter there) and then redirect to the actual URL

```
<a href="redirect.php?redirect=http://domain.com>URL</a>
```

As per your code, it should be something like

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {

  $title=$rows['title'];
  $desc=$rows['description'];
  $url=urlencode($rows['url']);
  //include 'index.php';
  echo "<a href='redirect.php?$url'><b>$title</b></a><br><a href='$url'>$url"</a><p>";
  }
```

And in your redirect.php file (count and redirect file)

```
if(!file_exists('counter.txt')){ 
  file_put_contents('counter.txt', '0');
}
file_put_contents('counter.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('counter.txt')) + 1);
header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirect']);
```